# getRangeAt() -- error if no text is selected

Tags: javascript, dom

I use this simple Javascript code to retrieve text that was selected on a webpage:

```
var userselection = window.getSelection(); //user selection will be a Selection-Object
var rangeObject = userselection.getRangeAt(0);
```

The code works fine if text is selected. If I just click in the text that could be selected I get a range object too, it is collapsed as expected.

But if I don't select nor click, Firefox throws this error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057
(NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)  [nsISelection.getRangeAt]" nsresult: "0x80070057 
(NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///home/jan/Webprojekte/test-range
selection.html# :: who :: line 16" data: no]
```

Is there a clean way to prevent the error but still notificate the user that no text was selected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: check the selection's `rangeCount` property first. If it's zero, don't call `getRangeAt()`.

Answer (score 2):

i got the same problem. but in my case i had rangeCount equals 1. accidentaly i've found this way to solve the problem

you need to set timeout function and then everything goes well

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var userselection = window.getSelection(); //user selection will be a Selection-Object
    var rangeObject = userselection.getRangeAt(0);
},100)
```